# Calculate $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have found this integral on a physic book, in a part discussing the Stefan-Boltzmann law.

$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx = \frac{\pi^4}{15}$

Does someone know how to calculate it?

Thanks for any hint or answer.

Comment: Hint. $\frac{1}{e^x-1} =\frac{1}{e^x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - e^{-x}} =e^{-x} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}  e^{-kx}= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}  e^{-kx} $

Comment: This already has the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413571/how-can-i-calculate-int-0-infty-fracu3eu-1-du).